# Javac is not recognized

Tags: java, command-prompt, javac, system-variable

Recently I started a fresh install of windows 10, however javac seemed to stop working.

```
    C:\WINDOWS\system32>javac -version
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Here is a screenshot of my path:
[image]

Thanks! Please tell me if you have the solution.

Comment: Change all the path to the Java directory

Comment: You mean remove everything else from my path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make once again sure that `javac` is in the `PATH` that is set for your shell. Watch the output of `echo %PATH%`. I bet JDK's `bin` directory is *not* listed there.

If you set the `PATH` via System Settings in Windows, you have to close and re-open the terminal to make the changes take effect.

EDIT: Also remove the semikolon from the path to the JDK. Then it should work.

Comment: I think the jdk is there I am not sure though: C:\WINDOWS\system32>echo %PATH%
C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\codecandy\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin;" Also, I restarted my pc

Comment: Remove the quotes from the last entry.

Comment: They're not really there. This is what happens when I edit path: https://imgur.com/a/44yeK

Answer (score 0):

Try to rename ,Path' to ,PATH'

Hope that helpes

Comment: In windows, environment variables are case-insensitive.